# Setting up git server with web interface?

Tags: git

As our company would never let a third party like github anywhere near our source code, is anyone aware of any software or setup guides or blogs on how to setup a scm server like github, ie it would support

- Creation of repostories using a web interface
- Limiting/managing user access to individual repositories
- Browsing repositories online

If I can get this going I can see a potential mass migration from svn/cvs to git. (The only stumbling block I can see will be the windows Tortise SVN users having difficulty with the Git windows alternatives)

Comment: You might want to take a look at TortoiseGit http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/

Comment: I would like to add [gitlab](http://gitlab.org) which the closest you can get to github. Just adding information for this question for everyone's interest.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Gitorious](http://gitorious.org/) seems to support everything you ask for; its sources are [freely available](http://gitorious.org/gitorious) and can be hosted on your own servers.

Comment: GitLab acquired Gitorious. Gitlab (community edition) is available for free from https://about.gitlab.com/

Comment: gitlab is terrible and bloated now. the buying out of gitorious was only to eliminate possible competition. imo a d*ck move by gitlab.

Answer (score 19):

There are a few open source git hosting software / forges: both [Gitorious](http://gitorious.org) (in Ruby) and [InDefero](http://www.indefero.net) (in PHP) have freely available source. The code used to manage repositories by [repo.or.cz](http://repo.or.cz) is also open-source and freely available as [Girocco](http://repo.or.cz/w/girocco.git).

There is [GitHub:FI](http://fi.github.com) "self-hosted" version of GitHub software... but it is proprietary and expensive.

There are even more git web interfaces: **gitweb** (in Perl, distributed with Git), [cgit](http://hjemli.net/git/cgit/) (in C, offers caching), [git-php](http://github.com/josegonzalez/git-php) and [GitPHP](http://www.xiphux.com/programming/php/gitphp) and [ViewGit](http://viewgit.sourceforge.net/) (all in PHP), [Ginatra](https://github.com/narkoz/ginatra) (in Ruby, uses Sinatra framework).  A few more can be found at [InterfacesFrontendsAndTools](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/InterfacesFrontendsAndTools) page on git wiki.

Comment: by today's standards all these are out of date GitList is a very good option nowadays

Answer (score 5):

Use [Gogs](https://gogs.io/). It's a lightweight git server with web interface written in Go language. It looks like a github clone, but not at all. There is an internal bugtracker and wiki, but they can be replaced by external in settings. Take a look at it.

Answer (score 4):

[GitHub:FI](http://fi.github.com/) is an "inside-the-firewall" edition of GitHub, and very slick. It's also a lot easier to install than gitorious. The downside is, it's very expensive. We looked but had to pass.

We opted for gitosis for repository management with github for browsing. The one thing it lacks is the ability to create a repository using a web interface, although I suspect that could be cobbled together.

Answer (score 4):

I tested my self on a virtual machine [GitLab Community Edition](https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-ce/)

It works great. It is free (with some limitations).

Comment: We have been using this for years. Works fantasticly well.

Answer (score 4):

I found GitLab to be very very very resources hungry. Officially, you should have 4 GB of RAM, just to get started. This is not an option for a small virtual server.

Therefore, I recommend [GitList](http://www.gitlist.org/), where you may even contribute yourself, if needed.

Comment: GitList in my opinion, has the most beautiful and useful interface of everything else out there.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are looking for but you might not need a web interface.

You could also create a linux server and run git-deamon on it. Then you could use ssh to restrict user access. It is also possible to just create a network share and rescrict access that way.

There are lots of web interfaces for browsing, but I have found none that would run on window out-of-the-box, that could also create/modify a repositorie. A lot of the web interfaces just won't work in windows. Or maybe I didn't looked hard enough... As mentioned before [InterfacesFrontendsAndTools](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/InterfacesFrontendsAndTools) is a great source to start looking.

> The only stumbling block I can see will be the windows Tortise SVN users having difficulty with the Git windows alternatives

Try [GitExtensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/), it is very easy.

Comment: Cool, never seen the "GitExtensions" before, definitely worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider [Gitea](https://about.gitea.com/) as a solution for your self-hosted source code management (SCM) server. Its a open-source, lightweight, and easy-to-install solution that is very similar to GitHub in terms of its web interface and functionality.