# How to use Git with "multiple (thousands) projects" in one-repo?

Tags: git, svn, migration, github

We have a big SVN repo with multiple projects in it. Something like - http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/

Our repo is slightly more complicated since it has "project" at multiple-levels as well! We are planning to move to Git.

My concern is - I heard Git doesn't allow you to work on partial repos (based on PATH)
So even if I need to work on say `http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/rtsocial/trunk`, the entire repo will get downloaded. Is this true? Is there any workaroud for this?

We are planning to use GitHub so we cannot afford to have buy plans with 1000s of private repos for all our projects. We prefer keeping our most of projects in one big repo since projects are very small (wordpress theme, wordpress plugin, etc)

Apart from GitHub plans restriction, managing 1000s of repos will be a big administrative tasks I guess (we have more than 40 users in SVN and every month few more gets added)

Is there any way to go ahead with Git or should we stay with SVN only?
On sidenote, if Git prefers "one project = one repo", any alternative to GitHub where "unlimited private" repos are allowed?

Thanks all for help in advance.

Comment: What lead you to want to use GitHub? It seems completely inappropriate for your situation. As a side note, [please don't add signatures or tag lines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: We want GitHub for our open-source projects.

Comment: Does your existing SVN repo mix closed- and open-source projects? How do you manage that?

Comment: Self-hosted SVN is closed and for private project. Our wordpress themes & plugins are present on wordpress.org server. Apart from wordpress, we want to release some more work in open-source where we are anticipating a lot of "distributed" development... Because of all this, at some point, we felt we should switch to Git (and GitHub). We will go to Git for sure, and may use self-hosted http://gitorious.org/gitorious and/or GitHub.com (for public-repos). Exploring gitorious at the moment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In git, you should look at setting up separate repos for each of your project. What you said about "cloning" the entire repo to get a sinle project is correct, and there are no workarounds for it. ( don't get confused with terms like sparse checkout etc. - the term checkout is different in Git than from SVN. ). There is no concept of cloning only a particular folder in Git, like one can in SVN.

Since you mention projects are small, however, you can group some of them logically, like themes etc.

You can also look at `BitBucket`, which allows you to have **unlimited  free private Git repositories**. Or you can host the repos on your own server, it is pretty straightforward. With something like `gitolite` you can pretty easily administer and maintain many repos.

Comment: we plan grouping as you have suggested but we have more than 500 theme projects for clients. In terms of raw-storage, repo is around 1GB. By the way - better using words like "projects" - essentially, can we work on "parts" of repo in Git? I guess in "single" large project also - at some point, a contributor may need to add/delete/edit a section of project only.

Comment: @rahul286 No, in git you will have to get the entire repo to work on it. There is no concept of cloning only a particular folder within the repo like you would in SVN. Also, like I said, look at BitBucket. Or host the porject yourselves. When you use the projects with gitolite or something, I believe you can administer and maintain many projects.

Comment: I will go with self-hosted Git in that case. Any open-source/low-cost alternative for web-based Git interface? GitHub Firewall is way too costly for us.

Comment: @rahul286 - You can look at cgit, gitweb etc for web interface and also gitolite for repo management. https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite

Comment: Thanks. I also found - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627643/setting-up-git-server-with-web-interface

Answer (score 1):

> My concern is - I heard Git doesn't allow you to work on partial repos (based on PATH) So even if I need to work on say http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/rtsocial/trunk, the entire repo will get downloaded. Is this true? Is there any workaroud for this?

Yes. You cannot check out only part of a repository

Use one repo per project. There is no other sensible way to organize things. You can implement a hierarchy via submodules, which allow you to include a separate repo as a "sub project" of a different repo.

Git depends on sane content boundaries to work well. If you try to dump "multiple thousands" of projects into a single Git repo, you will have an absolute unmanageable disaster, guaranteed.

On a final note, Git != GitHub. You are not *required* to pay for Git hosting on GitHub to use Git, and I can't see why you would since you obviously don't intend to use any of GitHub's social coding features with 1000+ private repositories.

Any machine can host a Git repository for people to push and pull from. Why not just install your "thousands" of repositories onto a cheap Linux-based server somewhere in your office? Anything with sufficient hard drive space to hold the projects will do, a 10 year old machine with a 100GB hard drive could do the job.

> On sidenote, if Git prefers "one project = one repo", any alternative to GitHub where "unlimited private" repos are allowed?

GetHub sells the ability to licence and install a local copy of their software, called [GitHub Firewall](http://fi.github.com/). You will be able to configure unlimited private repositories as well as administer users etc. Pricing [starts at $5000/year](http://fi.github.com/pricing.html).

Comment: generally such things invite disasters. But some use-cases are exceptional. This public SVN repo - http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/ has more than 10000 "projects" and more than 5000 contributors working in it. Can't Git be used in cases like this?

Comment: @rahul286 Git is ideally suited for a situation like that, but not when you have 10k projects *already* in Subversion. The problem isn't Git, the problem is transferring 10k repositories from one VCS to another.

Comment: Thanks. We can manage one-time headache as we want to use Git and GitHub. Main reason to switch to Git is - we want to contribute more in open-source (preferably using GitHub.com). As I asked to Manoj - can we work on "parts" of a big repo in Git? Like "download" a "folder", make some changes, "upload" it back to repo? (sorry for my choice of "words" but I think I better express my intention using plain-english words rather than risk mentioning wrong Git commands)

Comment: Regarding - "GitHub's social coding features with 1000+ private repositories" .... we already have 8-10 projects in open-source on wordpress SVN. Reason we are moving to GitHub so that all our private+public projects can be managed from 1 place.

Comment: @rahul286 You cannot download just one directory from a Git repository. You get the entire thing, or you get none of it. This is why it is virtually *mandatory* to have one project per repository. You simply cannot place 1000 projects in a single repository and have anything remotely usable.

Comment: As far as the one-time headache, If you have 1000+ projects in a single SVN repo, I would throw out the history and start a new Git project for each directory. You could write a trivial bash script to do this for you. [Splitting a single SVN repo into multiple Git repos isn't bad](http://daneomatic.com/wp/2010/11/01/svn-to-multiple-git-repos/), doing so for 1000 Git repos is going to be painful.

Comment: Thanks. At this point I'm convinced GitHub is not good for our private projects. Also GitHub Firewall is way too costly for us. I am aware that I can host Git on our linux server locally (we are hosting our SVN locally as of now).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4442/discussion-between-rahul286-and-meagar)

Comment: @meagar: It seems a pity to throw out the history.  Isn't it possible to split into multiple Git repos while keeping the existing SVN history?

Comment: @KeithThompson In our case throwing out history is fine with us. We will be maintaining current SVN server in read-only form for a year unless new system gets working smoothly. So we can refer to the history in old-system. Plus any SCM we use mostly for "archival" purposes and 980% projects never gets edited once they are deployed.