# Any GitHub alternative which supports "online editing"?

Tags: github, ace-editor

I am researching alternatives for GitHub and one essential feature I am looking for is - https://github.com/blog/905-edit-like-an-ace

I will prefer a self-hosted solution but we are open to online-hosting as well. In fact, GitHub.com itself is perfect fit for us except for their plan-structure. We want the option to have "unlimited repositories" which is not possible in any GitHub plan. ([why we need "unlimited" is  discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851407/how-to-use-git-with-multiple-thousands-projects-in-one-repo/))

So far 2 solutions we liked so far are - [Gitorious](https://gitorious.org/gitorious) and Indefero. They are both nice. Though gitorious looks more polished, Indefero comes closer to our requirements.

**Important features we are looking for in "Web-based" inferface are:**

1. Repos management (add/remove/edit)
2. User management (add/remove/edit)
3. Team management (add/remove/edit)
4. Access control.
5. **Online editing** (essential because small-edits can be done very quickly in this way)

Any suggestions. Or any "hacks" to make online-editing possible in Gitorious or Indefero or in any other solution. Any other git-hosting will also work if they provide above features + unlimited repos.

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: Did you happen to find answers to your questions? Feel free to post and accept yours if none of ours was to your liking!

Comment: Not yet. Looks like GitHub has this feature exclusively. :-(

Comment: @Zolomon http://gitlab.org/ added online editing sometime back.

Comment: https://rhodecode.com has also online editing, including add/upload/edit/delete files. Supports reach text editor. All of course wrapped into very advanced permission system.

Comment: https://git.idehub.cn pasted Eclipse online http://www.eclipse.org/ecd/ on top of GitLab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if GitLab supports it yet, but take a look at http://gitlabhq.com/! It's the most promising GitHub alternative yet, it's for self-hosting though.

Comment: Looks nice. Will check this right away.

Comment: Amusingly, their sources are on github ... :)

Comment: @snogglethorpe They aren't here to replace Github, they're here to be an option to http://fi.github.com/ :)

Comment: @Zolomon When you posted http://gitlab.org/ did not provide online editing. But they added this feature and we are using it from sometime.

Answer (score 2):

GitHub itself provides [online editing](https://github.com/blog/905-edit-like-an-ace), but you can also try [Cloud9 IDE](http://cloud9ide.com/).

Answer (score 1):

There is [GitHub:FI](http://fi.github.com/) which is basically self-hosted GitHub.

Comment: Its way too expensive at the moment. We don't mind paying but 5000 USD/per year is way to much. :-(

Comment: @rahul286 - Yeah, but your question only stated that you need a plan with unlimited repos. This is a plan.

Comment: Ya. This is GitHub's plan!! If it would have been acceptable, why would I come here looking for alternative!

Comment: @rahul286 -  All I am saying is you said you want unlimited (private) repos and in your question you just said there is no plan with unlimited (private) repos.. You did not even talk about FI, but now you comment as though you knew about it.

Comment: by giving link to [previous related discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851407/how-to-use-git-with-multiple-thousands-projects-in-one-repo/) I thought anyone will get to know it was suggest before there. Anyway, I should have made myself clear.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays I would suggest you a combination of [GitLab](http://gitlabhq.com/) and [Cloud9 IDE](https://c9.io/). For both the source code is available and running online in any modern browser.
Please consider that, GitLab and Cloud9 having many dependencies to 'heavy' environments (Python, Ruby, Node.js, PostgreSQL, ..).

Comment: GitLab already added support for online file-editing. Unless you need complete IDE in browser, Cloud9 IDE is not required.