# Git web interface that can create new repositories?

Tags: git

I'm looking for something that I can install on my VPS that would be similar to GitHub or BitBucket. I have read the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627643/setting-up-git-server-with-web-interface) that is similar, however the solutions are outdated. I'm looking for something that...

- Is Open Source
- Has the ability to create new repositories
- Has the ability to create users and manage their permissions for repositories

I have tried [GitList](http://gitlist.org/) but it is lacking the functionality that I'm looking for. It seems more like an interface to view characteristics of repositories, rather than manage them.

I would also prefer that this web interface run on PHP, but that is not a requirement. Furthermore, if something like this doesn't exist, are there any "gotchas" that I should be aware of before creating one myself?

Comment: GitHub Enterprise?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer GitHub Enterprise is not open source.. (first bullet)

Comment: Try softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ItayB Yes, BTW if you're looking for a serious Git web interface probably it should be one of the best choices for now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/) is still a good option

> - Is Open Source

[Yes](https://about.gitlab.com/features/#community) The Community Edition is under MIT license

> - Has the ability to create new repositories

Yes - it is a basis

> - Has the ability to create users and manage their permissions for repositories

Yes through the Project or the Group